# Visual studio .csproj file looks different in notepad than in the VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csproj

I have strange situation and I am wondering the following thing:

In Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise, Unload project, Edit .csproj file it have at least 2000 lines of configuration.

But when I open the same file in Notepad ++ it has only 1000 lines.
Where are the rest?

At the end of the file there is:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\RazorGenerator.MsBuild.2.4.1\build
\RazorGenerator.MsBuild.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages
\RazorGenerator.MsBuild.2.4.1\build\RazorGenerator.MsBuild.targets')" />
```

But I cannot see it in the notepad++. Furthermore if I remove the line above git in Visual Studio (Team explorer) shows that the file has changes. But `git diff SitefinityWebApp.csproj` doesn't return any results. I cannot understand that.

Also the `<compile>` tags are missing in Notepad too .

Comment: You are looking at to different files. Open the containing folder from the project context menu and compare it to the path you are opening in notepad. Try to modify the project file in notepad while having it open in VS - it should notify you that the project was modified outside VS and ask if you'd like to reload.

Comment: YES, Someone included two .csproj files at the same place ....